# Get a Drawable from an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

As the title describes, I want to get a `Drawable` from an `ImageView` programatically.

I searched on the internet and I can't find how can I do that.

Comment: An `ImageView` is a `View`, so it can't be transformed into a `Drawable`. What are you trying to do? Do you need a `Drawable` for a specific image?

Comment: i found the solution, that was easy: imageView.getDrawable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ImageView is called myImageView:

```
myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImageView.getDrawingCache());
```

Make sure you call this after the layout is done: Use [the famous OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html)

Comment: i found the solution, that was easy: imageView.getDrawable()
I will consider this as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: Well I am sorry (: I thought your situation is a bit more complicated :p.